# How to read entire files in Puppet verbatim (without parsing like template)?

Tags: puppet

I need to create a bunch of `ssh_authorized_keys` resources. The [resource](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/ssh_authorized_key.html) expects its `key`-attribute to be the public key itself -- there is no way to refer to a *file* containing the key.

Because the keys are very long and because I already have them in files, I'd rather Puppet read them from the files instead of me quoting them in the manifest.

I can imagine a few other use-cases too.

Is there already a function to read a specified file *verbatim*, without attempting to interpret them as `template()` does?

For public-keys I can, actually, get away with `template()`, but that carries an overhead of a parsing-attempt. Also, in some other cases, depending on the file's contents, the parsing may, actually, "fail" or, worse, not fail, but quietly alter the contents...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there already a function to read a specified file verbatim, without attempting to interpret them as template() does?

The `file()` function will read and return the contents of a file on the Puppet master (or wherever the catalog's being compiled), similar to `template()` as you described.

- [file() function documentation](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/function.html#file)

Call it with a path such as `ssh_keys/foo.key` to load the file `ssh_keys/files/foo.key` within the modulepath.

Note that this function requires Puppet 3.7 or higher to load from the modulepath in the same way as `template()`. Prior to that it only worked with absolute paths, though has been in every major release.

Answer (score 0):

Use the resource type [`file`](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/reference/types/file.html#file-attribute-source) with a defined attribute `source`. My puppet environment, for managing the ssh keys, actually just imports the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file as a file.

Comment: That only works when you have _one_ trusted key per account. The `ssh_trusted_keys` resource can combine multiple keys into the `authorized_keys` file of the same user. Your proposal would not be acceptable for `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`, for example, if you had more than one operator-level employee...

Comment: And anything in the authorized_keys is the public key for each user, so is it acceptable to publish the one file containing all four root-level user keys?

Comment: What such "publishing" says is: "_this accounts are allowed to login as me_". Sort of like: "_these people all have keys to my apartment_". Whether publicizing such knowledge is Ok or not depends on the account... `sshd` does not insist on the file being unreadable to others -- as long as no one else can _modify_ it.